# aes.js & crypto.js best use

Tags: javascript, cryptography, aes, pbkdf2

The quick start guide tells us that we can use [aes.js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) this way :

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase"); 
var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
```

But is it safe enough ? Encrypted is an array with a lot of information (key, iv, salt, cyphertext).
But isn't safer to use PBKDF2 to derivate the password ? Like this :

```
var salt = CryptoJS.lib.WordArray.random(128/8); 
var key512Bits1000Iterations = CryptoJS.PBKDF2("Secret Passphrase", salt, { keySize: 512/32, iterations: 1000 });
var iv  = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('101112131415161718191a1b1c1d1e1f'); 

encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", key512Bits1000Iterations, { iv: iv });  
var decrypt = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, key512Bits1000Iterations, { iv: iv });
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the bottom of the page of [aes.js](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) you pointed at you will find:

### *Interoperability With OpenSSL*

*Encrypt with OpenSSL:*

```
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -in infile -out outfile -pass pass:"Secret Passphrase" -e -base64
```

*Decrypt with CryptoJS:*

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/aes.js"></script>
<script>
    var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(openSSLEncrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
</script>
```

So `aes.js` will use OpenSSL compatible key derivation if you use a passphrase.

---

Now if you look at the key derivation mechanism performed by OpenSSL, [EVP_BytesToKey](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual%3aEVP_BytesToKey%283%29), you will find this remark:

*Newer applications should use more standard algorithms such as PBKDF2 as defined in PKCS#5v2.1 for key derivation.*

Comment: Can you comment on interoperating with code that calls EVP_BytesToKey() with a non-standard value for the "count" parameter (e.g. > 1)?

Comment: Huh, missed that old remark. Anything is better than 1, you'd expect something much higher than 40K now, probably 100K or higher as iteration count. Of course you'd not be compatible with the standard call without iteration count, but I suppose that's obvious.